# Plugin Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP 1.0.0.1 injection failed. Installation exit code: -1

Tags: azure, deployment, rdp

I've tried to deploy my application into the Azure Worker role but could not get it done successfully. I hope somebody can help me.

After the error, I can see the error "Plugin Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP 1.0.0.1 injection failed. Installation exit code: -1" in my Windows Azure Portal.

If I do RDP, I can see the error message in details
Install command for plugin Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP 1.0.0.1 program D:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP\1.0.0.1\RemoteAccessPluginLauncher.exe exited with non-zero exit code -1.  .  MessageId       = 3004 SymbolicName    = EVENT_PLUGIN_INSTALL_EXITED_WITH_SUCCESS Severity        = Success Language        = English Install command for plugin Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP 1.0.0.1 program D:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP\1.0.0.1\RemoteAccessPluginLauncher.exe exited with zero exit code -1. .  MessageId       = 3005 SymbolicName    = EVENT_PLUGIN_INSTALL_STARTED Severity        = Success Language        = English Executing install command for plugin Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP 1.0.0.1 program D:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP\1.0.0.1\RemoteAccessPluginLauncher.exe.

Do anybody know what happens?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "If I do RDP"?  How are you configuring RDP?

Comment: I mean if I connect to the worker role via RDP and then check the Event Viewer, I see this error.

Comment: I don't think that error has anything to do with your service and is likely benign.  Check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Error in downloading version manifest for Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions.RDP from: http://rdfepirv2by1prdstr01.blob.core.windows.net/bfd5c281a7dc4e4b84381eb0b47e3aaf/Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Extensions__RDP with exception: There is an error in XML document (1, 1)..

Comment: The blog post I mentioned should help you troubleshoot this issue.  If the blog post doesn't help then I would recommend opening a support incident at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/ so that someone can dig into this issue with you.